# How to include an OR condition into Exists?

Tags: sql-server

I want to select a name and a year. Why I get both year although I select 2020?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Person_Table]
    (
      Person nvarchar(500) NULL, 
      Name2 nvarchar(500), 
      Year_N int
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO Person_Table (Person, Name2, [Year_N])
VALUES ('Ken,Brian,Mike,','A,B,','2000'),
       ('Mikem,Briane,Kenny,','C,D,','2020'),
       ('Dodo,Chris,Mike,','A,B,','2020');

-------------------------------------------------
DECLARE @Person NVARCHAR(100) = 'Mike',
        @Date int = 2020

SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[Person_Table]
WHERE EXISTS 
              (Select * from string_split(Person,',') 
               WHERE value in (@Person))
              
OR EXISTS     (Select * from string_split(Name2,',') 
               WHERE value in (@Person))

AND Year_N = @Date
```

Microsoft SQL Server 2019

Comment: Because of your `OR`. Wrap the `OR` clauses in parenthesis and you get the expected results. Though what you should *really* being doing is fixing your design; don't store delimited data in your database.

Comment: Agreed, this structure should be represented by at least 2 different tables, maybe 3. Learn about database design, normalisation and relationships so you can implement a usable structure.

Comment: `OR` in SQL is different to English. In SQL, `OR` is logical disjunction, in English "or" (in this context) is a logical injunction ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction )

Comment: Try `where (exists (...) or exists(...)) and year = ...`

Comment: @Bohemian thank you man. You solve it.

Comment: @MisterXAGE_ Welcome to the site! We’re all here to help each other.